# AWS VM:- Execute tests on multiple threads in parallel with SPecrun

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, specrun

[image]I've AWS VM and i'm trying to run the Parallel tests with specrun and Profile transformation but it is only running for one thread and failing for other and test is getting skipped . Is there any settings we need to enabled on AWS VM ? or may be issue with my Profile ?

look at screengrab for error .

Note: Same setup will work on Physical box and i can able to do parallel run.

[image]

Comment: what part fo the process is creating the backup of the config file? is that necessary? Surely they should all just be reading the config

Comment: @SamHolder Look at my new attachment and let me know if anything